# In pytorch, can we conditionally train a model based on the label of a sample?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

For example, we have labels 1,2 and 3 in a dataset. If a sample is associated with label 3 then we don't train the model using this sample. Otherwise, we use this sample to calculate the loss along with the gradient. I wonder how we can do this during the training phase and whether the following code is correct or not.

```
for i in range(len(outputs)):
    if targets[i].item() != 3:
       targets_.append(targets[i].item())
       outputs_.append(outputs[i].cpu().detach().numpy())
      
loss = loss_fn(torch.Tensor(outputs_).requires_grad_().to(DEVICE, dtype=torch.float), 
               torch.Tensor(targets_).to(DEVICE, dtype=torch.long))
                
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: This way probably won't work since you detach from the graph and convert to numpy. That breaks the gradient flow. Changing it back to tensor won't work like this. In case your loss is cross entropy by any chance, then you can use the ignore_index option (set it to 3 i.e. the label you want to not train the model on). For other loss as well, I think you can create a mask of (targets == 3) and multiply it with the loss vector before taking the mean of the loss. This will zero out the terms you don't want to consider in the optimization.

Comment: @akshayk07 hi, Thanks for your comments. I just realized that the gradient flow will be broken in this way and it doesn't make any sense if I just put a new tensor into a loss function.

Comment: Can you not just filter out those entries in both outputs and targets using `outputs = outputs[targets!=3]; targets = targets[targets!=3]`?

Comment: @jhso yeah you are right. That is another way -- filter out the sample associated with label 3 during the data preprocessing phase.